# How to change position of gear icon and display name on top

Tags: 2013, ribbon, top-link-bar

Is there a way to move these two items as shown in following screenshot to move to some other location?
I want them to be displayed below at some other place so that I can completely hide this top bar but can't seem to make it work.
I have tried to use "position:absolute;top:100px;" but although it moves the item but clicking on it doesn't open menu like it should.

[image]

Comment: Nobody knows about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it by copying both divs that display "user name" and "gear and help icon" using Firebug.
Then I pasted those divs at desired location and modified them slightly and it is now working.
After that I set the original divs to "display = none".

Comment: You modified the ASPX markup or the resulting HTML? If you changed the resulting HTML markup as seen by Firebug, you'll probably find that you made them static instead of dynamic and now everyone sees your own name when they log in...

Comment: No they are not static. That's what I thought so but I have tested it by logging in with 2 different users have different rights and the menu shows items depending on rights. The only thing that was static is the user name which you can make dynamic very easily.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can move the two items you identified (welcome menu and site actions) easily by changing the masterpage. If you look in the masterpage there is a div titled "SuiteBarRight" which contains both items.

Comment: Don't change the masterpage, make a copy, make adjustments to your copy and make sure your sites uses the new masterpage.

Comment: Yeah exactly what Robert said. I should of said make a copy of the masterpage before you make the changes. Don't want to edit the OOTB masterpages.